# Workaround for when nothing is found from a query in GORM

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I'm doing something like this in one of my methods:

```
    def colorId = Store.findByName(color).id
    def shadeIds = Shades.findAllByColor(colorId).shadeId
    println "IDS" + shadeIds //sometimes this is empty ([])
    MyShop.getAll(shadeIds).shades
```

from the above code whenever `shadeIds` is empty `[]` I get a SQL error when doing `MyShop.getAll(shadeIds).shades` Is there a workaround to this?

My temporary workaround is:

```
    def colorId = Store.findByName(color).id
    def shadeIds = Shades.findAllByColor(colorId).shadeId
    println "IDS" + shadeIds //sometimes this is empty ([])
    if (shadeIds.size() == 0)
      shadeIds << -1
    MyShop.getAll(shadeIds).shades
```

Comment: what result are you expecting for searching by empty ids list?

Comment: I'm expecting nothing in return if the list is just empty.

Comment: Why not `if (shadeIds) { MyShop.getAll(shadeIds) }`

Comment: @birdy you can also use the if(shadesIds.isEmpty()){MyShop.getAll(shadeIds)}

Comment: @axierjhtjz the groovy truth already checks if the list is empty and return false in this case.

Comment: @SérgioMichels just for curiosity, groovy truth it´s been there since always or on any recent update?

Comment: @axierjhtjz I don't know since when it exists, [but the post](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/GROOVY/Groovy+Truth) in the Groovy site is from 2010, and his first version is from 2007.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The workaround results in an unnecessary database call that you have guaranteed to not return anything. Use this instead:

```
def shades = shadeIds ? MyShop.getAll(shadeIds).shades : []
```